# Cannot find my include file during enabling shell settings for VSCode setup

Tags: javascript, json, shell, visual-studio-code, include

I am trying to enable the shell settings for myproject
Here are the codes in c_cpp_properties.json:

```html
Cannot find "c:\msys64\home\AisyahJeff\myproject\.vscode\include".
```

```html
{
    "env": {
        "mySpresenseSdkPath": "c:\\msys64\\home\\AisyahJeff\\spresense"
    },
    "configurations": 
    [
        {
            "name": "Spresense SDK",
            "intelliSenseMode": "${default}",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/include",
                "${mySpresenseSdkPath}/sdk/apps/include",
                "${mySpresenseSdkPath}/sdk/modules/include",
                "${mySpresenseSdkPath}/sdk/modules/asmp/worker",
                "${mySpresenseSdkPath}/sdk/system/include",
                "${mySpresenseSdkPath}/sdk/bsp/include",
                "${mySpresenseSdkPath}/nuttx/include",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++11",
            "compilerPath": "${config:spresense.env.toolchain.path}/arm-none-eabi-gcc"
        
        }
       
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Therefore, there's an error that I encounter, which is saying that it cannot find my include file in the "myproject" folder. I looked for it in the folder and I couldn't find the include files as well. The error look like this:

Cannot find "c:\msys64\home\AisyahJeff\myproject.vscode\include".

Does anybody have any similar encounter?
Btw, I am using windows 10.